# How to get the property of an element after transformation?

Tags: jquery, css

I am doing a transformation of the width of an element.
In my jquery I add a class, and in the css I describe the transformation. If I query now with jquery the width of this element after adding the class I get the current width of this element, but this is not the final width of it.
How do I get the final width? Is there an event, transformation finished or something like this?
Should I use a timeout or jquery watch?

/kind regards
Christian

EDIT:
Even better now: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/PDLmj/)

On the first click the method width() returns 100, after the transformation it returns 200. How to get the result on the first click?

Comment: Code is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the element you are transforming has a display type of block (display: block), otherwise you can't modify the width of the element.

Html:

```
<a href="#">Bigger</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    console.log($(this).width());
    $(this).addClass('bigger');
    console.log($(this).width());
});
```

CSS:

```
a {
    width:100px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.bigger {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: My question was not, how to transform, it was how to query some properties (in that case the width) of an element after adding the class, when the transformation takes a second or so. See my code in the edit. Thx